# Multiple WHERE conditions WITH NOT IN

Tags: sql, where-clause

I am working on tuning a stored procedure. The stored procedure is doing a SELECT and has around 50 WHERE conditions. The SQL is similar to below. Can you please let me know if there is a better way to check these conditions

```
SELECT * FROM table A 
JOIN table B
ON A.ID = B.ID
WHERE
  (
            (
            A.name = 'abc'
            and B.AID not in ( 111, 222) 

            )
        or

        (A.name = 'def'
        and B.AID not in ( 222,1113,111,654,199,43,243,643,754244,2434) 
        )
        or

        (
        A.name = 'etd'
        and B.AID not in ( 111,345,54,34,454) 

        )
        or

        (
        A.name = 'ent'
        and B.AID not in ( 111,188,199,1647,128006) 
        )
        or

        (
        A.name = 'yyy'
        and B.AID not in (111,188,1113,1647) 
        )
        or

        (
        A.name = 'uuu'
        and B.AID not in (111,188,1113,1647) 
        )
        or

        (
        A.name = 'jyf'
        and B.AID not in (111,188,1647,344,45444,645) 
        )
        or

        (
        A.name = 'tut'
        and B.AID not in (111,222,1113,1647) 
        )
```

)

Comment: Well, it certainly looks awful.  Without knowing what your database schema looks like, it's hard to tell you how this could be improved.

Comment: You could store the condition in a table, more or less. Then join against that table, instead of formulating a weird series of conditions. That will be faster and gives you the possibility to document the system. (simply add a remark what this row `'tut', 111`is meaning (and why you don't want to have it))

Comment: There is some consolidation of some of the where clauses... A.name='uuu' and A.name = 'yyy' has the same list of excluded B.AID values.  Otherwise I don't think there is much of a way to reduce this statement much.  (Will be happily surprised if someone has a better answer).

Answer (score 1):

1. Create a table to map the names and IDs:

   ```
   Name    AID
   ------  ------
   abc     111
   abc     222
   def     222
   def     1113

   ..etc
   ```
2. Use a LEFT join to exclude matches:

   ```
   SELECT * FROM table A 
   JOIN table B 
     ON A.ID = B.ID
   LEFT JOIN Exclusions e
     ON A.name = e.name
        and B.AID = e.AID
   WHERE e.name IS NULL   -- not in exclusion table
   ```

or a NOT EXISTS:

```
    SELECT * FROM table A 
    JOIN table B 
      ON A.ID = B.ID
    WHERE NOT EXISTS(
        SELECT null FROM Exclusions e
        WHERE A.name = e.name
         and B.AID = e.AID
        )
```